# Flipped image for Layer

Tags: ios, swift

so I am trying to create a flipped image for CAShapeLayer.

and I have the following code

```
shiplayer.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "spaceship").withHorizontallyFlippedOrientation().cgImage
    view.layer.addSublayer(shiplayer)
```

But the image rendered by the shiplayer is still the original unflipped image .

I tested it on an UIImageView, and the image is flipped properly.

What can I do to flip the image for a CALayer>?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CGImage is the underlying bitmap; it knows nothing of the image properties. So draw the image, flipped, into a new image graphics context and use the resulting image as the basis for a new CGImage.